# How to mark the start of the shell session from Vim?

Tags: shell, vim, vim-fugitive

When I am using `vim-figitive` it often shells out for commands like `git push` and so on.

Every time it opens a shell I see some leftovers from the previous session, something like:

```
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

It sets me off *every* time because I can't figure out if this is the output from the current session or the previous one.

Is there a way to mark it with some sort of line every time I shell out from vim? Something like this in `.zshrc` would do it I think:

```
if [ -n $VIM ]; then
  echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
fi
```

**Update**
It works when I run `:sh`, but not when I run commands from `vim-fugitive`. Is there is a way to intercept `system()` calls or whatever it is using?

Comment: Yes, subshells have a few Vim-specific environment variables set: `$VIM`, `VIMRUNTIME`, `$MYVIMRC` that you can use in your init script.

Comment: You could patch the plugin to use the shell in the way that you like.

Answer (score 0):

From @tpope:

> My recommendation would be to look into disabling the "alternate
>   screen" for your terminal emulator (or terminal multiplexor). That's
>   what I do.

Just add the following to `tmux.conf`

```
# tmux.conf
# For tmux , the alternate-screen option defaults to on
set-window-option -g alternate-screen off
```